# Unknown field "follow_redirect" while fetching facebook ad creatives from API

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to get details of an ad creative from Facebook's ad API. According to the [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcreative/), follow_redirect is a gettable field. However, when I add it to the "fields" argument, facebook throws this:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: follow_redirect.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 100
>      }
>   }

My request :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxx?fields=id,title,body,image_hash,image_url,name,link_url,type,object_id,related_fan_page,follow_redirect,auto_update,story_id,preview_url,action_spec,follow_redirect&access_token=xxxxx
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `follow_redirect` field on an adcreative, it's a flag you provide when creating the creative itself, but it isn't a property of the resulting creative